# Java formatting strings in JList

Tags: java, swing, jlist, renderer

After hours of no luck with `String.format()`... I turn to you. Anyhow I have a JList that I populate with new entries here's the code:

```
private void addModule(final JList browse, final JList select){
    browse.addMouseListener(new MouseListener(){
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            String addable = browse.getSelectedValue().toString();
            if(e.getClickCount() == 2 && getSelectedTower() != null && addable.charAt(0) == ' '){
                String data[] = new EPTModule_Model().moduleData(addable.trim());
                String module = data[0];
                String module_cap = data[1];
                String module_cpu = data[2];
                struct.addElement("> " + module + "Capacitor:" + module_cap + "CPU:" + module_cpu);
                select.setModel(struct);
                setSelectedModules(1);
            } else if (e.getClickCount() == 2 && getSelectedTower() == null){
                new EPTEvent_Model().eventNoTowerSelected();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}
        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}
        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
    });
}
```

Anyhow the thing is when I use my application now as I add new Elements to the list they are not all the same length so I get outputs like this:

1. xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx             Capacitor:  555  Cpu:  10
2. xxxxxxxxxx               Capacitor:  555  Cpu:  10
3. xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  Capacitor:  555  Cpu:  10

As you can see that is not very readable I want to output > Capacitor... to be aligned in same column regardless of xxxxxx string length. Anyhow the max length of xxxx strings is 47 chars if that helps.

Comment: Maybe you want to write a [custom renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#renderer)?

Comment: Or use a monospace font, or use a table (since it's tabular info), etc.

Comment: Have a look at MouseAdapter. It saves you having to override methods you don't want to add code to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
struct.addElement(String.format("> %47s Capacitor: %s CPU: %s", module, module_cap, module_cpu));
```

Comment: Can you take a look at this image: 
http://img685.imageshack.us/img685/1036/33338215.jpg

The Capacitor string should all be aligned in a same column..

Comment: Ah, I see. The problem is, you must use a fixed-width font (eg. Courier New) if you want the text to be perfectly aligned. Othewise, letters don't have the same width, and nothing can be aligned.

Comment: Oke so i set the font to "monospace" seems to work out but can you check this image:
http://img843.imageshack.us/img843/5183/newzmb.jpg

I would rather have the > name ..space.. capacitor aligned in collumn

Basicaly the white space u see in the image on left i would rather have on right.

Comment: Easy, change %47s to %-47s, it will be left-aligned :)

Comment: BTW, you can also use the same trick to align the others numbers it you need to (I see the "CPU" info is not well aligned)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
String part1 = String.format("%47s", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
String line1 = part1 + " Capacitor: 555 Cpu: 10";

String part2 = String.format("%47s", "xxxxxxxxxx");
String line2 = part2 + " Capacitor: 555 Cpu: 10";

System.out.println(line1);
System.out.println(line2);
```

No matter the length of the "xxx" parts, they will always have 47 chars of length, and they will be padded with white spaces to the left. All the "Capacitor..." parts will be aligned in the same column.